# Class with generic property MUST be generic?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Let's say I have this class

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public List<T> FooList { get; set;}
}
```

And this class is used by another class like:

```
public class Bar
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }  // THIS DOESNT COMPILE
}
```

The above solution doesn't work because it says my generic type `Foo` requires 1 type argument. 
In my real scenario, I don't think it makes much sense to propagate the generic to `Bar` class, like:

```
public class Bar<T>
{
    public List<Foo<T>> Foos { get; set; }  // Not the solution I want
}
```

So I would like to know: which is the best solution here, if any? Do I really need to make my `Bar` class generic? In Java, if Im not mistaken, I could do something like `List<Foo<?>> Foos` and it would work...

**Edit**

So, as asked, I'm giving the concrete example.
I am doing some DTO classes for [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/). 
Highcharts, among a lot of other objects, has the `series` object. This `series` object have the `data` property which can be pretty much anything: A list of numbers, a list of pairs of numbers, etc, etc.

So my generic class would be the series:

```
public class SeriesDto<T>
{
     public List<T> Data { get; set; }

     // Other options ...
}
```

And it would be used by the `HighchartsDto` class:

```
public class HighchartsDto {

    // Lot of things..
    // ...

    public List<SeriesDto> Series { get; set; } // doesn't compile
}
```

It doesn't make sense to make `HighchartsDto` generic because the same chart can have different types of series.

Comment: C# does not allow generic properties in a non-generic class. It allows generic methods, however. But it is really not obvious why would you want such thing? This could lead to a case where one can call set with a List<Foo<int>> and `get` with a List<Foo<string>>

Comment: But `Bar` essentially contains a `List<List<T>>` so it needs to be generic

Comment: @ja72 - No it doesn't. `T` must be resolved for `Bar` to contain it.

Comment: @Enigmativity - where in the _OP_ does is mention what is `T` in order to make `Foo<T>` a concrete class?

Comment: Effectively, not enough information to answer effectively is given. Please describe how `Foo` and `Bar` are intended to be used.

Comment: Java generics are not the same as C# generics, and rely on completely different principles under the hood. In Java, you will experience type erasure after compilation, whereas C# will preserve the type information all the way down to the byte code. This means that C# generics are, in a way, a lot more strict when it comes to what the compiler will accept, and how you can constrain (or free) generic types.

Comment: Thanks @YannickMeeus. Given your answer on how different generics in C# are from Java, I guess my only solution (given the edit I made) is to go with some abstraction (an interface or even an abstract class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "This series object have the data property which can be pretty much anything: A list of numbers, a list of pairs of numbers, etc, etc."

A `List<T>` is not a good for a collection that can be anything. A `List<T>` is a collection of one thing of type `T`. Maybe you want the good old `ArrayList` which is a collection of `object`, and thus it can be anything. In essence you have to decide which is a common type the contents can have.

1. **Contents have nothing in common**, other than deriving from `object`

   ```
   public class SeriesDto
   {
       public ArrayList Data { get; set; }

       // Other options ...
   }

   public class HighchartsDto
   {

       // Lot of things..
       // ...

       public List<SeriesDto> Series { get; set; } // doesn't compile
   }

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var dto = new SeriesDto();
           dto.Data.Add("A string");
           dto.Data.Add(1001);
           dto.Data.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));

           var list = new HighchartsDto();
           list.Series.Add(dto);


           TimeSpan time = (TimeSpan)list.Series[0].Data[2]; // 15 seconds
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Contents have a basic interface in common** which includes all properties and methods that is shared with all types

   ```
   public interface ISeriesData
   {
       DateTime CreatedTime { get; }
   }

   public class StringData : ISeriesData
   {
       public StringData(string name)
       {
           this.Name = name;
           this.CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
       }
       public string Name { get; }
       public DateTime CreatedTime { get; }
   }

   public class IntegerData : ISeriesData
   {
       public IntegerData(int value)
       {
           this.Value = value;
           this.CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
       }
       public DateTime CreatedTime { get; }
       public int Value { get; }
   }

   public class SeriesDto
   {
       public List<ISeriesData> Data { get; set; }

       // Other options ...
   }

   public class HighchartsDto
   {

       // Lot of things..
       // ...

       public List<SeriesDto> Series { get; set; } // doesn't compile
   }

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var a = new StringData("A");
           var b = new IntegerData(1001);
           var dto = new SeriesDto();
           dto.Data.Add(a);
           dto.Data.Add(b);

           var list = new HighchartsDto();
           list.Series.Add(dto);


           DateTime time = list.Series[0].Data[0].CreatedTime; // time
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Make HighChartsDto Generic** and inherit from it the concrete classes.

   ```
   public class SeriesDto<T> 
   {
       public List<T> Data { get; set; }
       // Other options ...
   }


   public class HighChartsDto<L, T>  where L : SeriesDto<T>
   {

       // Lot of things..
       // ...
       public int SomethingElse { get; set; }
       public List<L> Series { get; set; } // doesn't compile
   }

   public class HighChartsStringDto : HighChartsDto< SeriesDto<string>, string>
   {
   }

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var a = new SeriesDto<string>();
           a.Data.Add("A");
           a.Data.Add("B");
           a.Data.Add("C");

           var b = new SeriesDto<string>();
           b.Data.Add("1");
           b.Data.Add("2");
           b.Data.Add("3");


           var list = new HighChartsStringDto();
           list.Series.Add(a);
           list.Series.Add(b);

           string x = list.Series[1].Data[2];  // "C"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ja72. When I said that `it could be anything` I meant anything of the same type. Like, each `SeriesDto` has a `List` of something all of the same type, but I got what you mean as well. I guess I will go with your nº2 solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can add an interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    public List<T> FooList { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public List<IFoo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Backs for the answer. So there's really no more "direct" way of achieving this in C#? To me that interface seems hacky...

Comment: @JoãoMenighin - Achieve what? You need to give us your business requirement? Right now you're asking for a non-existent feature. If you could say what you're trying to do we might be able to give you an answer. Backs has done a good job of trying to do this for you.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin I really don't know, what do you want to do, so I just describe the most common way

Comment: I edit the answer with the concrete example... And now your solution seems to be the correct one since the same `Bar` object can have a list of different `Foos`

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is you haven't given a realistic example, just a hypothetical.

The following doesn't compile, because it doesn't knows what generic type you want to use? what should it guess?

```
public class Bar
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }  // THIS DOESNT COMPILE
}
```

If you understand `Bar`, then you could do something lie this and mark the type in advance, i.e Bar will always implement `Foo<int>`

```
public class Bar
{
    public List<Foo<int>> Foos { get; set; } 
}
```

If you want more power, and to choose the type at a later point in code, you can do this

```
public class Bar<T>
{
   public List<Foo<T>> Foos { get; set; } 
}
```

Or as *Backs* pointed out you can add an interface, all this is really doing though is hiding the members of `Foo<T>`, `List<T> FooList { get; set;}` is unusable in this context.

You need to work out what want, and why you want it, and maybe better explain it

Answer (score 1):

Althoug I'm aware that this solution is flawed, this would be another way to do this.

```
public class Foo<T> : Foo
{
    public List<T> FooList { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{

}
```

So you're creating a non-generic class from which your generic Foo derives.
Then you can do this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }  // THIS DOES NOW COMPILE
}
```

And then if needed you could cast the non-generic List to a list of your generic-type like this:

```
bar.Foos.Cast<Foo<GENERICTYPE>>()
```

But that requires you knowing which exact type it is going to be.